# Xamarin FFImageLoading Usage Clarification

Tags: xamarin.android, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp, ffimageloading

I see we use `FFImageLoading` like below

```
var cachedImage = new CachedImage() {
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    WidthRequest = 300,
    HeightRequest = 300,
  ...
    Source = <url or asset or resource location>
```

};

or in XAML:

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage 
  HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
    WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"
    DownsampleToViewSize="true"
    Source = "<url or asset or resource location>>
</ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

, so, I replaced all instances of `Image` in my UWP project and `ImageView` in my Android project with `CachedImage`.

But after reading through FFImageLoading documentation, I also see lots of
cases where images are loaded using `ImageService`.  For example:

```
ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(urlToImage).Into(_imageView);
ImageService.Instance.LoadCompiledResource(nameOfResource).Into(_imageView);
...
```

- What is the difference between these two ways?
- Why would I use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFImageLoading is a multi-platform library. `ImageService.Instance` methods are used to load images into native views (like `ImageViewAsync` on Android or `UIImageView` on iOS) and also for some advanced scenarios. There are also platform specific controls which internally use those methods, like:

- `CachedImage` for Xamarin.Forms
- `MvxCachedImageView` for native Android/iOS/Windows or MVVM Cross

They allow you for using things like bindings out of the box.

I advice you to use platform specific controls and use `ImageService.Instance` calls for advanced things. But it's entirely up to you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, ImageService.Instance is used only in code whereas CachedImage can be used in both code and XAML?

Comment: `ImageService` can be called in code, `CachedImage` can only be used in Xamarin.Forms (and it uses `ImageService` under the hood)